# Behavior of lapse function at infinity: stability of Minkowski

Tags: differential-equations, hyperbolic-pde, general-relativity

In the Stability of Minkowski Spacetime, Christodoulou and Klainerman prove a local existence proof for a particular class of quasilinear wave equation for a symmetric, traceless, covariant 2-tensor $k_{ij}$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$. On p.309 (in the print version), the authors claim that a certain term behaves better (in terms of decay at infinity) in the wave equation for $\text{div}(k)$, where $\text{div}$ is the divergence operator on $\mathbb{R}^3$: $\text{div}(k)_j = \nabla^i k_{ij}$. **My question is:** why? Details below.

In this question I include only the relevant parts of the equation; the irrelevant (for this question) parts will be denoted by $f$. Note that this is a *linear* wave equation (since it is a part of the iteration argument in the proof of local existence to the quasilinear problem). So suppose we have
$$
-(\phi^{-1}\partial_t)^2 k_{ij} + \Delta k_{ij} = \phi^{-2}\nabla_i \nabla_j \dot \phi + f.
$$
We are solving for the unknown $k_{ij} : [0, T] \times \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$, and $\phi : [0, T] \times \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ solves $\Delta \phi = |k[n]|^2\phi$. Here, $k[n]$ can be thought of as a fixed 2-tensor of the same type as $k$. (It is denoted as such since this question, again, is concerned with producing a "$k_{n + 1}$" solution to the linear equation above, in a typical hyperbolic equation iteration scheme.) Also, $\dot\phi$ denotes $\partial_t \phi$.

The iteration scheme provides us with the following bounds: $\phi - 1 \in H_{4, -1}, \dot\phi \in H_{4, -1}, k[n] \in H_{3, 1}$. Here $H_{s, \delta}$ is the weighted Sobolev space on $\mathbb{R}^3$:
$$
\|{U}\|_{H_{s, \delta}}^2 = \sum_{0 \leq k \leq s} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |(1 + |x|^2)^{(\delta + k)/2}\nabla^k U|^2\, dx.
$$

The authors claim that $\text{div}(k) \in H_{0, 3}$ and proceed by deriving, from the wave equation for $k$, a wave equation for $\text{div}(k)$ and applying energy estimates using the multiplier vector field $\langle x \rangle^3\partial_t$. In doing so, one must bound (as in standard energy estimates for linear wave equations)
$$
\|\langle x \rangle^3\Box \text{div}(k)\|_{L^2_x}.
$$
However, if we consider what happens in applying $\text{div}$ to the equation above, we see that we obtain
$$
\Box \text{div}(k)_j = 2\phi^{-3}\nabla^i \phi \nabla_i \nabla_j \dot \phi - \phi^{-2}\nabla^i \nabla_i \nabla_j \dot \phi + f.
$$
Yet it is straightforward to see that with the estimates given above for $\phi - 1, \dot \phi$, that (for instance) we do *not* have $\langle x \rangle^3\Box_{g_n} \overline{\text{div}}{(k)_j}\in L^2$. Indeed, the best we can do is place $\phi \in L^\infty$, and then (by weighted Sobolev embeddings) place $\langle x\rangle^{3/2}\nabla \phi \in L^\infty$. This leaves $\|\langle x \rangle^{3/2}\nabla_i \nabla_j \dot \phi\|_{L^2_x}$, but since $\dot \phi \in H_{4, -1} \implies \nabla_i \nabla_j \dot \phi \in H_{2, 1}$ only, this quantity is not bounded.

How is this bound obtained?

Comment: I tried to make your post easier to read. Let me know if I made any mistakes.

Comment: Why is there a $\phi^{-2}$ in your wave equation for $k$? The way the paragraph is written on page 309, it seems to be that certain cancellations should happen when you take the divergence. In your transcription of equation (10.2.21c) you used $\partial_t$ instead of $\phi^-1 \partial_t$, and I wonder if certain cancellations (say, allowing you to use (10.2.21a)) happen if you look at some of your omitted terms that you call $f$.

Comment: @WillieWong I typed $\partial_t$ here just for brevity (sorry) - I've edited the question to account for this (and also fixed a sign error), and double-checked this agrees with C-K 10.2.21c. The problem is that in $f$ (corresponding to $N_{ij}$ - other than the term I've picked out - in 10.2.17a) there are no other terms which are second spatial derivatives of $\dot \phi$, so I can't see how any direct cancellation would happen.

Comment: I'm wondering now if equation (10.2.17d) - the Poisson equation for $\dot \phi$ - can be used to improve decay of $\overline\nabla^2\dot\phi$.

Comment: The idea I had in mind is that you already have some preliminary decay rates for $k$, which you wish to improve. So instead of taking divergence of equation 10.2.21c, you first multiply by $\phi^2$, take the divergence, and then divide again. This way you don't worry about any $\nabla^2 \dot{\phi}$ term at all, since $\phi^2 N_{ij}$ gives you just $\nabla^2_{ij} \dot{\phi}$ whose divergence you can directly replace using (10.2.17d). The hope is that the error terms you generated from commuting with $\phi^2$ pairs well with the first-pass decay rate of $k$.

Comment: [Your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448966/behavior-of-lapse-function-at-infinity-stability-of-minkowski?noredirect=1#comment1164574_448966) won't work: because if you could do that you can directly estimate the equation for $k$, without passing to the divergence first. The $\nabla^2 \phi$ term is the problem to start with.

Comment: That makes sense. But it looks like the error term is $2\phi \overline\nabla^i \phi \Box k_{ij}$ (where $\Box = -(\phi^{-1}\partial_t)^2 + \Delta$), which we want to put in $H_{0,3}$. Since $\overline\nabla^i \phi \in H_{3,0}$, if we want to proceed directly via Sobolev embedding, we would need $\Box k_{ij} \in H_{0,1.5 + \epsilon}$. But $\Box k \in H_{0, 1}$ only, at least if you put absolute values on the RHS for $\Box k_{ij} = N_{ij}$. (No cancellation seems possible for the same reason it wasn't possible in my first comment in this thread.)

Comment: The first-pass decay rates you mention - do you mean the $\partial_t k_{n + 1}, \overline\nabla k_{n + 1} \in H_{0,1}$ in the paragraph on p. 309? It seems reasonable to expect that from these one might obtain the next order $\partial_t k_{n + 1}, \overline\nabla k_{n + 1} \in H_{1,1}$, in which case one would probably obtain $\Box k \in H_{0, 2}$, which would let us fix the error in my last comment.

Comment: That's what I was wondering about. I don't have my copy of C-K on me at the moment to check, so my previous comments should be considered just me spit-balling though. But it doesn't make sense for the same reason you just pointed out. You already know that $\Box k$ is at best $\phi^{-2} \nabla^2\dot{\phi}$, so you get $\Box k$ cannot be better than $H_{2,1}$ (can't create something outta nothing).

Comment: Another try: maybe a two-step process? Your argument gives $\Box \mathrm{div} k \approx \nabla \phi \nabla^2 \dot{\phi} \in H_{1,5/2}$, and the same should hold for $\mathrm{curl} k$. This gives that $\nabla \mathrm{div} k$ and $\nabla \mathrm{curl} k$ in $H_{1,5/2}$. Elliptic estimates then give $k\in H_{3,1/2}$.

Comment: Now, $\phi^2 \Box = - \partial^2_{tt} + \phi^{-1} \dot{\phi} \partial_t  + \phi^2 \triangle$, so  $\phi^2 \Box \mathrm{div} = \mathrm{div} (\phi^2 \Box) + \nabla (\phi^2) \triangle + \nabla (\phi^{-1} \dot{\phi}) \partial_t $. Key is that we don't have terms with two time derivatives. The first term we already argue have better decay. The second term we note $\triangle k \in H_{1,5/2}$ so the whole thing is in $H_{1,4}$. And the final term we have that $\nabla(\phi^{-1} \dot{\phi}) \in H_{3,0}$, while $\partial_t k$ should be in $H_{2,3/2}$, making the whole term in $H_{1,3}$.

Comment: I haven't checked all details. But this feels promising...

Comment: You're right, this does...I'm checking it now (but probably won't be able to finish today). One thing I'm unsure of in Step 1: to use elliptic estimates we need $\|(\text{div}, \text{curl})k\|_{H_{2,3/2}}$. Your argument (which I guess is energy estimates for $\Box(\text{div}, \text{curl})(k)$?) gives, by definition of these Sobolev spaces, the two highest order parts of this norm, but not - as far as I can see - the $\|(\text{div}, \text{curl})k\|_{H_{0, 3/2}}$ part.  From $\nabla(\text{div},\text{curl})k \in H_{1,5/2}$, can we conclude $(\text{div},\text{curl})k \in H_{0,3/2}$?

Comment: The energy estimates give also $\partial_t \mathrm{div} k\in H_{1,5/2}$, if you integrate in time you can get $\mathrm{div}k$ differs from the initial data by a term of $H_{1,5/2}$. The data is assumed to be in $H_{3,1}$, so its first derivative is in $H_{2,2}$. So this integration should yield $\mathrm{div}k \in H_{1,2}$ which certainly bounds $H_{0,3/2}$.